# Regular Expression for extracting Content between bracket with some exception on selected contents

Tags: regex

i want to extract contents between each brackets with some exception and the exception is if content has `\` character the reg must doesn't select it. for first part i use this code :

```
var paramReg = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
```

this reg also select this string `[param1]` and `[param2/p]` string but this string `[param2/p]` has a `\` in it's content and i don't want reg selected it . i know i can remove this kind of exception with for loop and then check for `\` but i want to know can i use Reg for this.

Comment: Use regex `/\[([^\\]*?)\]/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
var paramReg = /\[([^\\]*?)\]/g;
```